# How to manage rollback transaction of first api on the basis on another api

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions

On a button click i am calling three api separately in synchronous way, the problem is if last api fail then i can not roll back transaction of first two api. i can not merge all the api to make one api, is there any way to rollback the transaction of first two api if third api failed.

Comment: the simple answer is No. you can not roll back transaction from client side but if you have access to your api code . you can manage that problem in server side

Comment: how to manage in server side ?

Comment: for example you can save your data in a temp storage (db,file,etc)... after receiving all 3 requests successfully, save your data in the main storage. you can clean your temp storage with a timer(for example every 10 min)

Comment: in case of insertion not fetching data.